# Can I connecting a Bluetooth device to Quest 2?

Tags: unity-game-engine, bluetooth, oculus, oculusquest

I would like to connect a Bluetooth device (not headphone or keyboard ) to my quest 2. Currently my app running on Unity engine.

Does Quest 2 support this kind of scenario?
Is there any documentation available how can I do that as a developer?
Is the an example that I can look into? (preferred in Unity)
Any information about BT connectivity support in Quest 2 will be warmly welcome :)

Comment: Also curious, I'm trying to connect a BLE device directly to an Oculus device - looking to subscribe to notifications on a certain known characteristics and also write to the device.